# Where can I put paginate()?

Tags: ajax, laravel, laravel-5, bootstrap-4, laravel-4

I am trying put `paginate(10)` to add a pagination later, but when I added it it gives me this error:

> `Undefined property: Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator::$product`

Here is my controller where I want add the `pagination(10)`:

```
 public function index()
    {
        $user_id = auth()->user()->id;
        $user = User::find($user_id);

        return view('your')->with('product', $user->product);
    }
```

I did try this:

```
 public function index()
    {
        $user_id = auth()->user()->id;
        $user = User::find($user_id)->paginate(10);

        return view('your')->with('product', $user->product);
    }
```

How can I avoid the undefined property error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually `find` function is used for getting only 1 result and you are applying pagination on that which is resulting into an error.

You might be wanting the products data to be paginated, For that do like this

```
public function index()
{
    $user_id = auth()->user()->id;
    $user = User::find($user_id)->product()->paginate(10);

    return view('your')->with('product', $user);
 }
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: @seique3 My Pleasure Bro :), Can you just upvote my answer ?